# SQL Server Agent not starting automatically on server reboot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, sql-agent-job

I have noticed that SQL Agent does not start automatically after a reboot/shutdown on a few of our servers (SQL server starts up fine). The service is set to automatically start in windows. When we start SQL agent manually, it starts fine.

Comment: Anything interesting in Agent error logs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add your windows level user in following path:

Click on Start - Run - **Secpol.msc**

Go to: **Local Policies - User right assignments**

Ensure the user account your running the SQL Agent Service under has the following assignments:

1. Act as a part of the Operating system
2. bypass Traverse checking
3. Lock pages in memory
4. Log on as a service
5. Log on a batch job
6. Replace process level token

If not, please add them and try restarting your system. Your SQL Server should be now be automatically starting as a service.