# SQL Server service doesn't start anymore automatically if I make a Windows restart

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have Windows 10 build 1511, where I have installed SQL Server 2014.

After installation everything is OK.

I've made several times shutdown on Windows 10, and after if I turn on my PC everything is OK.

But if I restart the system, after the restart, the SQL Server service remains stopped (startup type is `Automatic`). I try another restart and shutdown, but the service doesn't start automatically anymore.

I've started the service manually, and after the service is started and everything works ok. If I shut down everything, it is ok afterwards. But if I just restart, the problem that I've described above appears again.

What can I do ?

Thank you !

**Update**

It seems that the problem is already reported to Microsoft :
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1873617/sql-server-not-coming-online-after-os-upgrade-to-windows-10-even-when-startup-type-is-automatic

Comment: Can you check the windows event log for any indications as to why it won't start? Maybe a service it depends on that wasn't started (or isn't starting anymore)?

Comment: There are no indications.at all.

Comment: Can you check the SQL Server service dependencies (through properties). Verify that any dependent services are in fact configured to also start automatic.

Comment: And general advice... don't be too snappy to upgrade your OS to the newest (or libraries, or runtime environment, NET version etc). It might be a new update that is bugging your installation. And I've not heard many good things about Win10.

Comment: The sql server service does not depend to any other service.

Comment: @TT Sorry friend , but if the newest OS , or other libraries have bugged my installation ,  then why this service starts ok and works ok , when I make shutdowns , and only when I make restart doesn't start automatically ( but  starts ok manually ) ?

Comment: Honestly, I'd ask Microsoft. Maybe you found a bug.

Comment: Try set the service as `Automatic (delayed)` see what happens? Also have you checked the SQL Server error log?

Comment: Have you fiddled around with the Recovery options (tab in service properties), set `Restart the Service` for first & second failure? Also if you can't get any information from logs available to you, set Start Parameters (General tab) `-n -e error_log_path` and check what's being written to the error file (cf [Database Engine Service Startup Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx)).

Comment: I've tried with Restart the service to first or second failure. But the problem is the same. Also I've tried with start parametres , but no error is written to log file. It seems that when I do restart , the system ignore the Automatic Startup type of the service. And no error is generated.

Comment: @alex That's about all the advice I can give, not using Windows 10 being the most important. I assume you have a support contract with MS, report this as a bug.

Comment: @TT Now I'm detecting other services that have the same issue on Windows 10 . I have reformatted my PC , and after I have installed only sql server , but it's the same issue.

Comment: It seems that the problem is already reported to Microsoft : https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1873617/sql-server-not-coming-online-after-os-upgrade-to-windows-10-even-when-startup-type-is-automatic

Comment: You will note [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb5f2199-f283-4249-a029-53978d637148/sql-service-stops-working-after-windows-10-upgrade?forum=sqldatabaseengine) about the problem has as a solution something I've already suggested: *Change the startup type from Automatic to Automatic (Delayed Start)*

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @TT as I have noted above , I have detected that not only sql server service , but other services too have this issue. Do you think is a good thing to make all "Automatic Delayed" ? and as far as I know the Delayed service start running 2 minutes after the last automatic service is started. With this solution there will be too many services Automatic Delayed !!!

Comment: The real solution is: don't use Windows 10 until it has been properly vetted by professionals as a stable platform for production. And AFAICT that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @TT Honestly , do you know a Windows version that is full Stable ? Maybe windows XP latest version was about 90% stable , but this windows get this stable status only 10 years after creation date . What do you think , to wait 10 years before upgrading to Windows 10 ???

Comment: No I don't think you need to wait 10 years. I can speak only for myself here: I would never consider jumping to an OS that is merely half a year old and most definitely not for production environments. But to each his own I guess. You will eventually learn. Good luck!

Comment: @TT Ok , friend. Let's suppose that all the people in the planet will think like you , and no one use Windows 10 because it's new system and not very stable. Then how do you suppose that the problems this system may have can be reported and resolved ?  I think the users have an important role in detecting and reporting problems , so Microsoft will correct these problems and Windows 10 will became more stable.

Comment: The comment section is not a discussion platform. The *Good Luck* was me saying that I'm done with this discussion. Good luck!

Comment: You can just not reply , if you have nothing to say about my comments.

Answer (score 7):

If you starts services.msc and serach for the SqlServer service, in properties, set the startup as automatic delay instead of automatic.

Comment: Negative. We have 3 customers with this problem, tried this on all 3 of them, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same issue on Win 2012. and it looks like the same issue [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619950/sql-server-agent-not-starting-automatically-on-server-reboot):

Add your windows level user in following path:

Click on Start - Run - Secpol.msc Go to Local Policies - User right assignments

1. Act as a part of the Operating system
2. bypass Traverse checking
3. Lock pages in memory
4. Log on as a service
5. Log on a batch job
6. Replace process level token

If not, please add them and try restarting your system. Your SQL Server should be starting as a service. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Windows 10 and SQL Server 2014 Express.

The delayed start option didn't work for me, but here's what did work - granting higher DCOM permissions to the Network Service and Local Service accounts.

1. Click Start, type Component and then click the Component Services
   app
2. In Component Services, double-click Component Services, and then double- click Computers. Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
3. Click the COM Security tab.
4. In the Launch and Activation Permissions area, click Edit Default.
5. Click Add, type Network Service, and then click OK. While Network Service is selected, click to select the Allow check boxes for the following items:

   - Local Launch
   - Remote Launch
   - Local Activation
   - Remote Activation
6. Repeat step 4 for the Local Service account.
7. Reboot and SQL Server should not start automatically.

In my case, this is a development environment so I'm less concerned about the security implications of this change and more concerned about getting it to work. So be advised to check out potential security ramifications if that's important in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

pay Attention in suffix too

example: if in your user Secedit.msc is as contoso\usersql, in the windows service needs to be the same, I was putting usersql@contoso.com and was having problems to start the service automatic, after change to contoso\usersql, working fine

Answer (score 0):

follow the way,

```
SQL SERVER INSTALLATION CENTER (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2019\Configuration Tools) > Maintenance > Edition Upgrade
```

and restart service

Answer (score -1):

Another solution worked for me:

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Select SQL Server Services
3. Select any service (double click or right click and properties)
4. Go to "Log On" tab (My Log On settings was "This Account")
5. Choose "Built-in account" and "Local Service" under it.

Then I did this steps for every other services and it worked. I have no more problem while I am connecting to SQL Server Databases.

[SQL Server Services Log On Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ApVW.png)

Answer (score -2):

I faced this issue today , as my server is dependent on SQL server connection , that was also not booting up. It was simple in my case. I saw in services screen its status is STOP. So I started there ans it started working.
windows+R--> services.msc--> right click on the service and start it.

Comment: OP already acknowledged that it can be started manually and it works just fine. It's the automatic start which is a problem. This is like a problem "My car's wheel keeps falling off" and your solution is to "Put it back on". Of course, but the root problem is how to keep it from falling off again?