# SQL Server service does not start at start up

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have a fresh windows 10 installed computer, and I have installed SQL Server 2014 express. The service is set to automatic, but when I reboot the computer the service is stopped and I have to start manually.

The installation is a local installation in a computer, there is no problems with permissions nor other things, because I can start the service manually and it starts.

How the service is not started on start up?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Check the Application Event Log - it should tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: This question was just asked yesterday [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34797295/243373) on SO. It is a known bug (see the link at the bottom of the question). A workaround is to put the service in `Automatic (Delayed)` startup type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your service to automatic delayed start, and it will start:

[image]